# Insert date and time stamp via checkbox into specific cell?

Tags: excel, checkbox, timestamp

I have gotten this far in creating a macro which works and puts it into a cell which is great but there are 2 issues I have, one, the check box can be moved by right clicking and dragging which then impacts the cell where the date is going.

Please can someone advise how to stop the check box from being dragged and/or specify the cell the date stamp will go to regardless of the check box location?

```
Sub CheckBox_TimeStamp()
Dim VarCheckBox As CheckBox
Set VarCheckBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
With VarCheckBox.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 1)
If VarCheckBox.Value = xlOff Then
.Value = ""
Else
.Value = Date & " " & Time
.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End If
End With
End Sub
```